# Synonymize [persistent-volume-claims] and [kubernetes-pvc] with [persistent-volumes]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I have proposed a tag synonym for [persistent-volume-claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-volume-claims) -> [kubernetes-pvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-pvc), but I now think these both should be synonyms of [persistent-volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-volumes), which is a more generic term (see [Kubernetes Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)). There is no point in having a specific tag for PersistentVolumeClaims.

I cannot add that suggestion as long as the first proposal is *Pending Approval*. What are the steps to getting these new synonyms put into place?

Comment: The user-level tag synonym system is fundamentally broken and useless, so let's not focus on that. Let's instead focus on just fixing the problem. As a moderator, I can do this directly. Currently, I see [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpersistent-volume-claims%5D+-kubernetes+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bkubernetes%5D&searchOn=3) that are tagged [[tag:persistent-volume-claims]], but not obviously about Kubernetes. Are these questions correctly tagged? Are they actually about Kubernetes? Or do they argue that [[tag:persistent-volumes]] cannot be limited to Kubernetes?

Comment: @CodyGray thanks. Yes, all questions left in your search is related to either [openshift] or [minikube] which are both kubernetes distributions.

Comment: @CodyGray is it possible to remove my tag synonym proposal for [kubernetes-pvc] -> [persistent-volume-claims], such that I at least can propose the two new that I suggest in this post, [kubernetes-pvc] -> [peristent-volumes] and [persistent-volume-claims] -> [persistent-volumes] ?

Comment: The tag synonym proposal system is pretty much entirely broken. It works better to just have a moderator put the synonyms in place, which can happen via a Meta question justifying the rationale.